# Eclipse TreeViewer/ViewPart background click

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am developing a flashcard application using eclipse. I have a TreeViewer in a ViewPart, and I use it to display various categories. However, I cannot find a way to process a background click event. I do not have much experience with eclipse development, so maybe background is the wrong word.

I need something like this:

```
TreeViewer.setOnBackGroundClickListener(new ClickListener() {});
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Maybe adding a screenshot of the area you call background would help?

Comment: @Baz Added a screenshot.

Comment: It seems like bad UX, maybe you should add a button.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath What is UX? Anyway, the user needs to be able to add root categories, and that can only be done when everything is deselected.

Comment: User Experience, I meant that the user wouldn't think to click in that area. You might be correct about using that area to deselect though. What would be really clear is if you had a plus button next to each row, which creates a sibling to that row. A minus could delete them. That aside, have you tried TreeViewer.hookControl(Control)? Im not sure if the background is a Control, it might be.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath Now that I think about it, clicking the background is a bad idea. What if the list of categories extends past the viewing area? There would be no background to click. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the SWT layer:

`TreeViewer.getTree().addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {...});`

With this method I get notified of the click even outside the selection.